# In java, is there a way to "Join" a thread after it went to a waiting state instead of when it's done?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait

I'm trying to run a list of threads from a main, where one of them, let's call it `tLast`, should be started individually after the others entered waiting state. I know about `t.join` but as I understand it works only if the thread finishes it's work, and as I understand waiting doesn't count.
So far I tried this, after starting all threads but `tLast`:

```
boolean inSleepState = false;
while(!inSleepState){
    inSleepState = true;
    for(Thread thread: threads){
        if(thread.checkState != Thread.state.WAITING){
            inSleepState = false; 
            break;
        }
    }
}

tLast.start()
```

The main problem I see with this is that this is a busy wait, which is bad practice and ill adviced as far as I know, But I can't think of another way to do this. Btw I realise I can wait for each thread Individually and spare iteration over `threads`, but either way this is a busy wait.

Comment: You're probably looking for a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Please read tag info before tagging. Not all library routines have tags. Please tag by clicking on a tag choice to see info & avoid typos.

Comment: Is it possible to have your threads notify() an object when they reach their waiting state?

Comment: I dont really see why you would want that, but if your threads are in waiting state i hope its waiting on some object , be it timed-waiting or normal waiting , you could call [latch.countDown();](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/countdownlatch-in-java/) on each thread and then call *latch.await();  before calling tLast.start()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` method will only join with a thread after it has terminated.  A thread in WAITING state is not terminated.

So the direct answer is that you can't join a waiting thread.

But on the other hand, `Thread::join` doesn't do a busy wait.

The third thing to note is that relying on a thread's state to indicate something is rather crude.  If a thread is `WAITING` state, that tells you that it is waiting for a `notify` on some mutex.  It doesn't tell you which mutex it is using.

Now ... presumably ... you want your `tLast` thread to wake up when the other threads reach a specific state.  If that is what you are trying to achieve, a `CountdownLatch`, `Semaphore` or `CyclicBarrier` may be what you need.

Comment: As I recall I did use a `CountdownLatch` in the end, so this answer is helpful. It's not exactly what I needed, but it's close enough if you put the countdown in the right in the code.

Comment: Meaning, right before you want the thread to go to sleep, you make it count down and let the other thread that's waiting on the latch continue, so this way you make sure anything that the first thread had to do before going to sleep was done, and the second thread would wait for it to finish.

Comment: Well yes.  Unfortunately your question didn't show us enough context to determine what you were actually doing.  It is hard to advise a correct solution when you haven't been told what the problem is.  That's why we couldn't give you exactly what you needed. (If you read the last paragraph of my answer, you can see that I had to make a guess at the nature of the your problem ... in order to make some vague suggestions of classes that might help.)

Comment: Noted, I will try to be more informative next time. I do hope this thread might be helpful to someone else though.